# Adding tooltip for many Images in the same column in a grid. in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void MyGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

                    if (value >= lowtarg && value < Toptarg)
                    {
                        img.ImageUrl = "Styles/Images/AmberBox.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (value >= Toptarg)
                    {
                        img.ImageUrl = "Styles/Images/GreenBox.jpg";
                    }
                    else if (value < lowtarg)
                    {
                        img.ImageUrl = "Styles/Images/RedBox.jpg";
                    }

          }
```

I am doing this in server side and displaying the images in the grid view,

```
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="Status" runat="server" />

                        </ItemTemplate>
```

This  is the column in the grid view I am displaying the images.  How can I add tool tip for each image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the ImageButton's [AlternateText property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.alternatetext%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

From the MSDN doc:

> Browsers that support the ToolTips feature display this text as a
>   ToolTip.

(You'll need to specify *what* content you want to have in the Tooltip and where it comes from if you need more detail...)

Comment: I am having 3 different image for the same column, how can I give alternative text for the image button since each image represent different features. I tried to give the Alternative text property in server side but for no use. didn't work

Comment: @Mano What is the type of the variable `img` in your code above?

Comment: @Mano I take from the acceptance checkmark that you got this working... how did you solve the issue mentioned in your comment? :)